# Fixing broken PATH on macOS

Tags: macos, environment-variables

My PATH system variable is jacked up after I installed python 3.10 and 3.11 and then uninstalled them both. It still shows this inside when I `echo $PATH`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin...
```

I'm not very good with this stuff so could somebody walk me through how to get rid of that junk?

I tried going into zshrc and typing `export PATH= xyz/... (python shit removed)`, exiting, and saving, but then it prompts me `File Name to Write: /Users/Me/.zshrc`

When I press tab it makes some dinky noise but does nothing, when I terminate the terminal my change isn't saved.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in nano ~/. zshrc but what I was needing to look in zshprofile, that's where the it was saved. then I just put a # before the variable command and it's all good now.

Comment: Going forward, just install tools like that with https://brew.sh/